# Conditional deployment build step skipped if tests ignored

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I'd like to create a build that also deploys to a server too, all in the same build.  So the last step is the deployment step.  However I don't want it to deploy if the there are ignored tests but I also don't want the build to show as broken.  I could fail the build if there are ignored tests but that could cause instabilities in the code base, i.e. false positive.  I could solve it with 2 builds with one triggered off the other but again I'm not sure how I would look for ignored tests in build 1

I can track what is deployed by displaying version number from assembly info in the app and updating from the build.  Also I can check the build log to see if that build step was skipped. In this way I can see what build the server is running.

Am I going completely insane, does this make sense, should I be doing this, is there a better way of achieving this goal?  Any help, as ever, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to look for ignored tests? This sounds like a bad idea. If developers can't mark tests as `[Ignore]` next thing they will do is comment them out - that's not a win.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedy with BrokenGlass. Before we can answer the question of whether you're "going completely insane" we need to understand why you think not deploying if there are ignored tests is necessary.

Comment: @BrokenGlass I want to put acceptegration tests (using specFlow) in at the start of a feature.  Then implement it using red/green unit testing committing as I go.  Once I believe the feature is complete, fill in the step for specFlow remove the ignore and if it passes it deploys.  Previously I let it deploy incomplete features because programmers are at different stages and put specFlow in at the end.  I'm currently in a team of one, if I wasn't this would clearly be bad but just wondered if I could do it in this circumstance jst to try something new.